# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 16.04 ACER Aspire E14

Tags: 16.04, wireless, acer

I have been having problems with wifi since 14.04...I upgraded to 16.04 and tried `sudo apt-get update && upgrade` but it didn't work...I am quite new to Linux so I am not able figure out the problem. Here are some system information that I think maybe useful.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no

dmesg | grep ath
[   15.973132] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   16.816281] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   16.840523] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   16.840530] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   16.840543] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
[   16.840545] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
[   16.840553] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
[   16.840554] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
[   16.840562] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
[   16.840564] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
[   16.840572] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
[   16.840573] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
[   16.840576] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[   16.840578] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need firmware! Please try, with a working internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Reboot. Is it working? If not, please check:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware
```

We hope we see that the installed version is 1.157.13. If not, try:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.157.13_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot. Is it working?

EDIT: I suspect that the download was somehow corrupted. Let’s try again:

```
cd /tmp
rm -rf linux-firmware*
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.157.13_all.deb
ls -al
```

We hope the size is 44364698. If so, let’s install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.157.13_all.deb
```

If the size of the downloaded package is different, *stop* and post the size.

Please post any errors or warnings.

Comment: First one didn't work.Then checked with the second command and the version was 1.157... but after `sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware.deb` got this error message: `dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'linux-firmware_1.157.13_all.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input`

Comment: and this: `dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive linux-firmware_1.157.13_all.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode' to '/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream`

Comment: "First one didn't work." Any details? Couldn't reach the repository? Already the latest version? Errors? Warnings?? Also, if the response to the second command was that you do, indeed, now have 1.157.13 installed, then there is no need to proceed to the *wget* step and we then wonder why you have the firmware and it doesn't load.  Please clarify.

Comment: My bad...I actually should have noticed this error...after `sudo apt-get update` I'm getting this error message:[https://drive.google.com/file/d/19EbnuoGWoWxql175WgLmTeqKil85eNSV/view?usp=sharing]
and the second command tells me firmware is up to date..

Comment: Your apt-get errors should be the subject of a separate new question. They do not impact the firmware question. linux-firmware-1.157.13 does contain ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin so we wonder why it doesn't load. May we see: `ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377`? Also: `ls -al /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0`

Comment: `ls /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA93771 - nothing
`ls -al /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0` - https://drive.google.com/open?id=13-HtrEjqljZLFsB_fTqx5J9GiRe69V6D

Comment: I see reference to an apt source referring to Virtual Box. Is this a virtual machine? Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: I have VirtualBox installed

Comment: result of `rm rf linux-firmware` -> `rm: cannot remove 'rf': No such file or directory` `rm: cannot remove 'linux-firmware': No such file or directory
`

Comment: I have uploaded my Wireless info here, please take a look if it's of any help: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i-O4m4v422T1d326JEoFCpVliWPHq8WD

Comment: Sorry for my typo. It should be: `rm -rf linux-firmware*` By the way, the asterisk * is required. Please don't skip it as you did above. Please try again including the wget and dpkg steps.

Comment: Yep...size was fine...installed it...rebooted and wifi is running....Thank you so much for the help @chili555...really appreciate it...